# Funny behavior of randomForest predictions

Tags: r, random-forest

I am using R package 'randomForest' and have noticed that when I try to make predictions with a fitted randomForest object and pass the data used to fit the model as the "new data", I get back exactly the response values, despite the confusion matrix for the fitted model not being diagonal. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 <- rnorm(200) 
x2 <- rnorm(200) 
y <- x1-x2>0
D <- data.frame( cbind(y,x1,x2) ) 
D$y <- as.factor(D$y)

model <- randomForest(y~., data=D)
model

Call:
 randomForest(formula = y ~ ., data = D) 
           Type of random forest: classification
                 Number of trees: 500
 No. of variables tried at each split: 1

    OOB estimate of  error rate: 4%
Confusion matrix:
    0  1 class.error
0 111  5  0.04310345
1   3 81  0.03571429
```

Note the non-diagonal confusion matrix. Now, when I pass the original data to the "predict" function, I get perfect agreement, which is inconsistent with the confusion matrix.

```
p <- predict(model,D)
sum( p != D$y ) 
[1] 0
```

Is this a property of the model, or a misunderstanding on my part of what the program is doing? I rather doubt the former, because when I used "predict", without passing the data (which, I assume, gives the in-sample predictions), I get

```
p1 <- predict(model)
sum( p1 != D$y ) 
[1] 8
```

which gives me 8 disagreements, which concurs with the confusion matrix. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call predict(model) this return the out of bag predicitions performed by the random forest.

However, when you call predict(model, training_data) the random forest applies its prediction to the training set, leading to a perfect accuracy (unless you specified an early stopping criterion on the growth of the trees)

Comment: Thanks! What are "out of bag predictions"? Predictions made on the test data?

Comment: When you run a random forest, each tree is train on a random subset of the data (usually, around 60% of the lines and sqrt(nb of predictors) predictors (for classification)). Out of bag predictions are predictions on the remaining lines.