# Identifying Overfitting in Randomforest Model

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

does anyone know a good rule of thumb to identify overfitting in a model.  For example if I have a randomforest model can I look at the difference between the in sample error rate and out of sample error rate to identify overfitting?  If so, how big a difference implies overfitting?  Are there other metrics I should look at?

Comment: I can't propose a complete answer, but the training error of a random forest is usually very low (close to 0). You can find more information here, per example : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172129/funny-behavior-of-randomforest-predictions/172134#172134

Answer (score 1):

Inbag error for RF is not useful for much. Completely disregard inbag error or whether individual trees are overfitted. Out-of-bag error and/or a outer wrapped cross-validation scheme, such as 10-fold 10-repeats would be the measure of performance.